# Why is my copy assignment operator never called?

Tags: c++, c++14, assignment-operator

I' playing around with c++14 a bit and I am wondering why my assignment operator is never called. The implementation appears to be correct and I disabled the optimisations (`-fno-elide-constructors -O0`) Is this some kind of compiler optimisation I am missing or is something wrong with my code?

## Source Code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int num = 0;

#define LOG_LINE(a) cout << "\n" << (++num) << ".)------------------------> " << #a << "\n"
#define LOG_TEXT cout << "called " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"

struct Klass {
    Klass() { LOG_TEXT; }
    ~Klass() { LOG_TEXT; }

    // copy
    Klass(const Klass&) { LOG_TEXT; }
    Klass& operator=(const Klass&) { LOG_TEXT; return *this; }

    // move
    Klass(Klass&&) { LOG_TEXT; }
    Klass& operator=(Klass&&) { LOG_TEXT; return *this; }
};


int main() {

    LOG_LINE(expecting normal contruction - OK);
    auto k1 = Klass{};
    auto k12 = Klass();

    LOG_LINE(expecting assignment operator - FAIL);
    auto k2 = k1;

    LOG_LINE(expecting copy construction - OK);
    auto k3 = Klass(k2);

    LOG_LINE(expecting move assignment - FAIL);
    auto k4 = std::move(k3);

    LOG_LINE(expecting move construction - OK);
    auto k5 = Klass(std::move(k4));

    LOG_LINE(expecting destruction of remaining objects - OK);
    (void) k5;

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
1.)------------------------> expecting normal contruction - OK
called Klass::Klass()
called Klass::Klass(Klass &&)
called Klass::~Klass()
called Klass::Klass()
called Klass::Klass(Klass &&)
called Klass::~Klass()

2.)------------------------> expecting assignment operator - FAIL
called Klass::Klass(const Klass &)

3.)------------------------> expecting copy construction - OK
called Klass::Klass(const Klass &)
called Klass::Klass(Klass &&)
called Klass::~Klass()

4.)------------------------> expecting move assignment - FAIL
called Klass::Klass(Klass &&)

5.)------------------------> expecting move construction - OK
called Klass::Klass(Klass &&)
called Klass::Klass(Klass &&)
called Klass::~Klass()

6.)------------------------> expecting destruction of remaining objects - OK
called Klass::~Klass()
called Klass::~Klass()
called Klass::~Klass()
called Klass::~Klass()
called Klass::~Klass()
called Klass::~Klass()
```

## Additional Information

I am using:

```
clang ++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

compiled with:
    `clang++ source.cpp -std=c++1y -o s -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -fno-elide-constructors -O0 && ./s`

Comment: Despite the `=`, `auto k2 = k1;` isn't assignment. It's initialization and calls the constructor.

Comment: `auto k1 = Klass{}` This is initialization, not an assignment; it runs a constructor, not an assignment operator. The same is true for all occurrences of `=` in your code.

Comment: Ok, how should the source code look like to make an assignment? Or let me change the question a bit: When is the assignment operator invoked?

Comment: When you assign to an _existing_ variable, not when you initialize a new variable. e.g. `k1 = Klass{};`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
auto k2 = k1;
```

is copy initialization, not assignment; it'll call the copy constructor. If you change that line to the following it'll do what you expect

```
Klass k2;   // default construction
k2 = k1;    // copy assignment
```

Similarly

```
Klass k4;            // default construction
k4 = std::move(k3);  // move assignment
```

Comment: Thanks all. That was the bug in my head :-) Now everything is working as expected :-)